# React: Updating state of adjacent sibling elements

Tags: reactjs, use-state

First of all here's the codesandbox link to the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/adjacent-state-vqifg?file=/src/styles.css).

What I am trying to achieve here is to have 3 states for `<CellItem />` component, "**active**", "**inactive**", "**semi-active**".
When I click any `<CellItem />` component it gets the "**active**" state and takes the background color. However the problem is, I also want the "**adjacent**" cells to get "**semi-active**" state and take the half transparent versions of those colors. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the React answer to this is [lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

#### How does that apply here?

To translate your goal into actions, when a cell's state changes to "active", you want it tell the cells around it that their new state is "semi-active".

Lifting state would say that your parent component `App` should maintain the state of each cell. Here's an example of that component's initial state. Two cells for simplicity:

```js
const cellData = [
  { colorName: "red", alpha: "(255,0,0,0.5)", state: "inactive" },
  { colorName: "blue", alpha: "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)", state: "active" },
]
```

When a cell is clicked, it calls a callback it has received as `props`, i.e. `handleClick(cellIndex)`. That function in the parent knows about all the cells and can update any of them accordingly.

#### Why is this useful?

To quote the React docs:

> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common ancestor. Let’s see how this works in action.

In this case, the parent can "see" all the cells and their states, and it knows about the position of each cell relative to the others. That puts it in the right position to decide which of all the cells are "active", "semi-active", or "inactive".

Comment: So, do I use a initialState on parent that is an array on 16 elements? If so, how do I change a particular state in this situation?

Comment: @EnesCeylan you're already iterating over the colors, and reading the colors in RGBA. Those could be combined into one thing, perhaps an array of objects, that also contains the state of each cell.

Comment: @EnesCeylan I added an example array of what your initial state could look like.

Answer (score 0):

You either keep cell "state" at the parent level in something like a Grid component and dumb down your cellItems so state should be passed in as a prop

OR

you pass in 2 functions as props to bubble up the selection event onSelect and then handle an event on another. Then you have the other cellItems decide whether or not their state should change.

Also you've described the on behaviour but what about off?

Something like this - https://t976r.csb.app/